# How to sort multiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, array-multisort

i have wrote a script to produce an array of data but now want to display in order of score. The array outputs as follows;

```
[display_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => ACT_Web_Designs
        [1] => user1_design
        [2] => user2_design
    )

[proffesion] => Array
    (
        [0] => Web Developer
        [1] => web developer
        [2] => Web Developer
    )

[score] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 15
    )

[img] => Array
    (
        [0] => ./?0000=gif&0001=3fadb8c362ff39f3322909899ff14760&0002=prof_pic
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
    )
```

so in a nutshell I am wanting it to be converted as follows;

```
    [display_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => ACT_Web_Designs
        [1] => user2_design
        [2] => user1_design
    )

[proffesion] => Array
    (
        [0] => Web Developer
        [1] => web developer
        [2] => Web Developer
    )

[score] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15
        [1] => 15
        [2] => 6
    )

[img] => Array
    (
        [0] => ./?0000=gif&0001=3fadb8c362ff39f3322909899ff14760&0002=prof_pic
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
    )
```

I have been looking at asort() but cant get anything to work. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: are the data from a database?maybe you can sort the data before you put them into an array?

Comment: Yes the results are but its for a directory/search engine so the results are based on the most efficient way to get the relevant results from the query

Comment: It’s *profession* with one *f* but two *s*.

Comment: You have me thinking now. See the score is calculated after the results are retrieved, I thik a cron job would be better for this, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly where the `PHP`'s [array_multisort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) comes to use. It is a case where you want to sort many arrays based on the comparison happening in just one of them.

I've modified the array `score` to have distinct values.

```
<?php

$arr = array(
                'display_name' => array('ACT_Web_Designs','user1_design','user2_design'),
                'proffesion' => array('Web Developer','web developer','web developer'),
                'score' => array(12,6,15),
                'img' => array('./?0000=gif&0001=3fadb8c362ff39f3322909899ff14760&0002=prof_pic','','')
            );

var_dump($arr);
array_multisort($arr['score'], SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC,
                $arr['display_name'],
                $arr['proffesion'],
                $arr['img']
                );
var_dump($arr);


?>
```

[**Here goes a working demo.**](http://www.ideone.com/5GaSa)

Comment: Have you ever had the feeling that PHP has too many sorting functions? All you ever need to do, is find the right one and all your problems go away.

I learned a new one today, thank you.

Comment: @Christian: Agree, there are many sorting function. Each one is for a certain problem to solve. Its good that we don't have to write our own sort function most of the times.

Answer (score 1):

How about this simpler one

```
$arr = array("k"=>array("A","B","C"),"l"=>array(15,6,15),"n"=>array("k","l","n"));
array_multisort($arr["k"],SORT_NUMERIC,SORT_DESC,$arr["l"],$arr["n"]);
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it work to just [`rsort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) the score array?

```
rsort($data['score'], SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do this, i was just after a more efficient way;

```
$array = array(
            'display_name' => array(0 => 'ACT_Web_Designs', 1 => 'user1_design', 2 => 'user2_design' ),
            'proffesion' => array( 0 => 'Web Developer', 1 => 'web developer', 2 => 'Web Developer' ),
            'score' => array( 0 => 15, 1 => 6, 2 => 15 ),
            'img' => array( 0 => './?0000=gif&0001=3fadb8c362ff39f3322909899ff14760&0002=prof_pic', 1 => '', 2 => '' )
);

arsort($array['score'], SORT_NUMERIC );
foreach($array['score'] as $key => $val ) {
    $newarray['display_name'][] = $array['display_name'][$key];
    $newarray['proffesion'][] = $array['proffesion'][$key];
    $newarray['score'][] = $array['score'][$key];
    $newarray['img'][] = $array['img'][$key];
}

print_r($newarray);
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [display_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => ACT_Web_Designs
            [1] => user2_design
            [2] => user1_design
        )

    [proffesion] => Array
        (
            [0] => Web Developer
            [1] => Web Developer
            [2] => web developer
        )

    [score] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 6
        )

    [img] => Array
        (
            [0] => ./?0000=gif&0001=3fadb8c362ff39f3322909899ff14760&0002=prof_pic
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not re-sort them for you, but it will let you go through them in the order you want. You can reassign them if you want, but I'd just use this for the output order.

**Edit: This will not work, due to the possibility of non-unique key values. See Comments below, and learn from my mistake**

```
$sort_order = $array['score'];
arsort($sort_order);
$sort_order = array_flip($sort_order);
foreach($sort_order as $key){
    echo $array['display_name'][$key].' - '.$array['score'][$key];
}
```

Comment: We had the same idea! However you ran into a problem by using array_flip because scores are not guaranteed to be unique. See my answer for my variation.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. Thanks for straightening me out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use rsort()

```
<?php
$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
rsort($fruits);
reset($fruits);
while (list($key, $val) = each($fruits)) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

This example would display:

```
0 = orange
1 = lemon
2 = banana
3 = apple
```

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution that I could find would not reorder the data structure but merely access it in a different fashion.

```
$scores = $data['score'];
arsort($scores);
$keys_ordered_by_score = array_keys($scores);
```

Now you can, say, grab the display_name and "proffesion" that has the highest score by the following:

```
$first_place = $keys_ordered_by_score[0];
echo $data['display_name'][$first_place],
     ' is a ', $data['proffesion'][$first_place];
```

Of course, if you *really* need to reorder the data structure, this idea is useless to you. Any of the other answers using array_multisort() will likely suit that need.