# How to sort two OR MORE arrays by the order of first one?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have several arrays.

```
$a = array("E", "A", NULL, "D", "C");
$b = array("Dog","Cat","Horse","Bear","Zebra");
$c = array(12, 11, 20, 30, 19);
```

First array not necessary numeric and can contain nulls.

I want to sort all 3 array by the order of first, i.e. to get

```
"A", "C", "D", "E", NULL

"Cat", "Zebra", "Bear", "Dog", "Horse"

11, 19, 30, 12, 20
```

I.e. tuples ("E", "Dog", 12), ("A", "Cat", 11), (NULL, "Horse", 20), ("D", "Bear", 30), ("C", "Zebra", 19) should be conserved.

I don't care what happens with null cases: thay can stay in place or go to end or beginning.

Comment: $join =array_combine($a, $b);
ksort($join); array_values($join);   if you want rearrange the key use array_values

Comment: Nice move, to change your post from handling three instead of two arrays after 4 people have made an effort to supply you with an answer.

Comment: @Dims can you share the expected output for your updated question?

Comment: @RST title was not changed, check it. People have not read it carefully

Comment: @SahilGulati I did it.

Comment: There is a requirement to supply valid example data. People read your text, don't pay much attention to the title most of the time. So now the question ends up with 4 identical anwers all upvoted and none of them solve your issue.

Comment: @RST I agree that this is my fault too; simultaneously, title is also important, it is incorrect to ignore it. Also I didn't knew, that for two arrays there is so different solution, because I am not PHP guru

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort multiple arrays in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696610/how-to-sort-multiple-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) for sorting multiple array based on first array. See below example

```
$a = array("E", "A", NULL, "D", "C");
$b = array("Dog","Cat","Horse","Bear","Zebra");
$c = array(12, 11, 20, 30, 19);

array_multisort($a, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $b, $c); // $b and $c sorting based on $a
echo "<pre>";
print_r($b);
print_r($c);
```

Comment: Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope my post will help you out.. Here we are using two function `array_combine` and `ksort`. `array_combine` will combine `values` with the `keys` and `ksort` will sort an array by key

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784337)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$a = array(5, 1, 2, 4, 3);
$b = array("Dog","Cat","Horse","Bear","Zebra");
$combined=array_combine($a, $b);
ksort($combined);
print_r($combined);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Cat
    [2] => Horse
    [3] => Zebra
    [4] => Bear
    [5] => Dog
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make array like

```
$array = array(
          '1'=>"Cat",
          '2' => 'Horse',
          '3' => 'Zebra',
          '4' => 'Bear',
          '5' => 'Dog',
      );
```

This is achieved using array_combine($a, $b)
After that, you can use ksort on the combined array.

Comment: oops! just saw this same answer has been posted! :)

Answer (score 1):

use `array_combine` first parameter is take as a `key` second parameter is taken as `value` and use `ksort` to sort the array based on key . finally if want rearrange the key use `array_values`

```
<?php
 $a = array(5, 1, 2, 4, 3);
 $b = array("Dog","Cat","Horse","Bear","Zebra");
 $join=array_combine($a, $b);
 ksort($join);
 print_r(array_values($join));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `array_combine()` and then `ksort()`:

```
$a = array(5, 1, 2, 4, 3);
$b = array("Dog","Cat","Horse","Bear","Zebra");

$c = array_combine($a, $b);
ksort($c);

var_dump($c);

array (size=5)
  1 => string 'Cat' (length=3)
  2 => string 'Horse' (length=5)
  3 => string 'Zebra' (length=5)
  4 => string 'Bear' (length=4)
  5 => string 'Dog' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This. NULL will be in beginning of array.

```
$a = array("E", "A", NULL, "D", "C");
asort($a); // Sort array and maintain index association
echo "<pre>"; print_r($a);
$b = array("Dog","Cat","Horse","Bear","Zebra");
$c = array(12, 11, 20, 30, 19);
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    $b1[] = $b[$k]; //you can also check with isset() whether it exist or not in this array 
    $c1[] = $c[$k];
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($b1);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($c1);
```

[Click here for Demo](https://3v4l.org/Md7uD)